# Coq:How to prove that the size of difference elements in a list is less then then the list's length

Tags: lambda, coq

I want to use the following lemmas to prove the strong form pigeon_hole principle.

```
Parameter A:Type.
Parameter  var_dec : forall (x y : A),{x=y}+{~x=y}. 

Definition included (l1 l2:list A):Prop :=
              forall x:A,In x l1 -> In x l2.

Fixpoint inbool (x:A) (l:list A) :bool :=
           match l with
           | nil => false
           | x'::l' => match (var_dec x' x) with
                           | left _ => true
                           | right _ => inbool x l'
                           end
           end.

Fixpoint diff(l1 l2:list A):nat :=
  match l2 with
  | nil => 0
  | x::l' => if inbool x l1 then diff l1 l' else S (diff (x::l1) l')
  end.
```

for example.
diff [] {1,2} = 2;
diff [] {1,2,2} = 2.

```
Lemma diff_le_length_le1:
  forall a l, diff (a::nil) l <= diff nil l.


Lemma include_diff:forall l1 l2,included l1 l2 -> diff nil l1 <= diff nil l2.
```

The strong form pigeon hole princible.

```
Theorem pigeon_hole_princible_sf:
            forall r:nat,forall h p,
             r>0->
             included p h -> length p > length h*(r-1) -> exists x : A , count x p >r-1.
```

How to prove the lemmas?

Comment: Add more related tags, for quick response.

Comment: diff (x::[]) [] is equal to 0.

Comment: This is not a simple induction though.

Comment: In this example, if you start with diff nil l, during the execution of diff, there will be recursive calls where the first argument is not nil.  This gives a hint that you should prove by induction statements where the first argument to the diff function should be an arbitrary variable, instead of nil.  Try to find a more general statement than diff_le_length_le1, that is still always true, but where nil does not occur, and prove that one by induction.

Answer (score 0):

I've proven a generalization of the first lemma. You can find it [here](http://pastebin.ca/2310722).

The most difficult part was simplifying objects out of the left side of `diff`. I needed to prove the following:

```
inbool a l1 = false -> inbool a l2 = false ->    diff (a :: l2) l1  = diff l2 l1
inbool a l1 = false -> inbool a l2 = true  ->    diff (a :: l2) l1  = diff l2 l1
inbool a l1 = true  -> inbool a l2 = false -> S (diff (a :: l2) l1) = diff l2 l1
inbool a l1 = true  -> inbool a l2 = true  ->    diff (a :: l2) l1  = diff l2 l1
```

It would probably easier to prove things about this other algorithm for `diff`.

```
Fixpoint diff (l1 l2 : list A) : nat :=
  match l2 with
  | nil => O
  | a :: l3 =>
    if inbool a l1
    then diff l1 l3
    else if inbool a l3
      then diff l1 l3
      else S (diff l1 l3)
  end.
```